# Code in app delegate vs View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am learning Google Signin Firebase Authentication in swift 4 / XCode 9`.

In Firebase documentation they declare the `AppDelegate.swift` as `GIDSignInDelegate`. I would have normally expected the view controller as `delegate` to manage then the action for the SignIn, LogOut etc...

Can someone explain what is the difference in doing this in the app `delegate` vs the `ViewController` (if there is one). Are there pros and cons to use one rather than the other?

I personally find easier to do this in the `ViewController` or outsourced to a class, as perform segue and other operations are easier, but maybe is not the best solution?

Comment: AppDelegate is a singleton instance where as viewControllers are not. So adding a AppDelegate as delegate to GIDSignInDelegate gives you flexibility to trigger Firebase authentication methods from whichever the view controller you want and without worrying about setting your view controller as delegate in viewDidLoad. Because usually login states are gloabal to app and not just to specific ViewController it makes sense to add singleton as a delegate to GIDSignInDelegate but then app delegate need not be a place to dump all code, rather u can create a separate singleton class of your own

Comment: and enjoy all the benefits of singleton while keeping your app delegate clean. There may be scenario where login/signup appears on different ViewControllers in app, rather than adding each such VCs as delegate every time in ViewDidLoad it makes sense to have one common instance that deals with authentication process. Because this instance needs to be available to all Classes in your app making singleton instance makes sense but using app delegate does not. AppDelegate is not a dump yard for all common code in your app

Comment: This make sense :) thanks for the answer.

Comment: Am glad I could be of help :) If you think u its a opinionated answer go ahead and delete your question if you think its useful to others add your answer and accept :) Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AppDelegate is a singleton instance where as viewControllers are not. So adding a AppDelegate as delegate to GIDSignInDelegate gives you flexibility to trigger Firebase authentication methods from whichever the view controller you want and without worrying about setting your view controller as delegate in viewDidLoad. Because usually login states are gloabal to app and not just to specific ViewController it makes sense to add singleton as a delegate to GIDSignInDelegate but then app delegate need not be a place to dump all code, rather u can create a separate singleton class of your own – Sandeep Bhandari 23 hours ago
upvote
flag
and enjoy all the benefits of singleton while keeping your app delegate clean. There may be scenario where login/signup appears on different ViewControllers in app, rather than adding each such VCs as delegate every time in ViewDidLoad it makes sense to have one common instance that deals with authentication process. Because this instance needs to be available to all Classes in your app making singleton instance makes sense but using app delegate does not. AppDelegate is not a dump yard for all common code in your app – Sandeep Bhandari 23 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

Firebase documentation is not wrong suggesting `AppDelegate` since it's the first object that comes alive and is shared by the app. But your `GIDSignInDelegate` doesn't have to be neither `AppDelegate` nor a view controller. It all depends on your project architecture (structure). If your app is large and you are splitting your logic into several "modules" you could create a shared (singleton) object such as `SessionService` or `LoginService`, etc. which could be instantiated when the app launches and act as your `GIDSignInDelegate`.